# .net core use ConfigurationBuilder to get Azure keys

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to use the ConfigurationBuilder to get the encryption keys from Azure KeyVault? Right now, if we create a configuration builder, any access of the configuration object maps directly to the secrets, and not to certificates or key.

For example, if I do:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configBuilder) =>
                {
.
.
.
                    var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

                    var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient((authority, resource, scope) => 
                        tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback(authority, resource, scope));

                    configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyvaultUrl, kvClient,
                    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
.
.
.
}
```

and then in code, use it to access something like

```
        public HelperClass(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger)
        {
            var secret = _configuration["Blobs:Users:Key"];
        }
```

the config builder maps it tries to find the key (after translation) in the vault secrets and pulls it if it exists. How do I get it to also/instead check the keys or certificates and return that instead? Is it supported?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. Anyway, configuration stores strings, and you would likely want a certificate as X509Certificate2 object. So I'd say wrap configuration and keyvaultClient in a kind of SecretManager and get your certificates from there through KV API.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. I was trying to avoid the extra step of stringifying the certificate after renewing it periodically; seems that's not an option.

Comment: Please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-application-id-and-x509-certificate-for-non-azure-hosted-apps

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I am asking about. I want to retrieve a keyvault certificate through the Configuration provider

Answer (score 0):

I found this post that helped me retrieve certificates from keyvault. I switched my encryption from keys to certs and followed the method mentioned here:

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/07/03/azure-key-vault-certificates-are-secrets